# Using mentions and ID commands for user [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Can someone help? I wanted my commands to be able to be used with @olios or 49556804 *** 0471817. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but my code isn't working.

```
 let userLevel = mentions.users.first () || msg.guild.members.cache.get (args [0]) || msg.author
 const userLevelID = userLevel.id
 const userLevelName = userLevel.user.username
```

And I get something like this from the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

Can it be done at all, or it worked on mentions and ID?

Comment: Had you tried debugging down the chain to try to find what the issue is? I would try `console.log`ing things like `userLevel` and try to see what isn't working.

Comment: Overall, if I use ID, I get a lot more information from console.log

If I enter the ID, I get `GuildMember`,
and when I type mentions I get `User`

Answer (score 2):

While both `msg.mentions.users.first()` and `msg.author` return a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), `msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])` returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). Both User and GuildMember have an `id` property, but only `GuildMember` has a `user`.

If you try to get the `user` from a `GuildMember`, you will be fine, but you will always receive a TypeError if you try to get it from a `User`.

You can update your code to get the `user` from `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])` only. I used [optional chaining (`?`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to ignore it if there is no `args[0]` and fall back to `msg.author`.

The following will work with all three cases:

```js
let userLevel =
  msg.mentions.users.first() ||
  msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])?.user ||
  msg.author;
const userLevelID = userLevel.id;
const userLevelName = userLevel.username;

console.log({ userLevelID, userLevelName });
```

Optional chaining requires Node.js v14+. If you have an older version you can use a simple AND operator:

```js
let userLevel =
  message.mentions.users.first() ||
  (message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) &&
    message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user) ||
  message.author;
```

Comment: Everything is ok but this `?` Crashes bugs       `msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])?.user ||
                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`
and without `?` msg.author does not work

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Why do you have to scream? I don't think your answer is the same as mine though and I'm not sure if that works. It will crash if you use `args[0]` as there won't be `userLevel.tag`.

Comment: @olios What's your node version? It will only work with node v14+.

Comment: This ? `"nodemon": "^2.0.6"`

Comment: Nope, type `node -v` in your terminal instead. I've just updated my answer so it will work with older versions too.

Comment: PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx> node -v
`v12.18.3`

Comment: Yep, try the updated code above, it should work with node v12.